# hangman game trying to count down user attempts

Tags: c#

here is my code below I am trying to make it count down from 6 to 0 every time the user enters wrong letter but it will only come up as 1 for me.

```
 private void UserAttempt(string letter)
    {
        if(Active_Word.Wrong_Guess < 6 && lbGuessWord.Text.Contains("*"))
        {
            int Mask = 1 << (letter[0] - 'A' + 1);

            if((Active_Word.Number_of_Letters & Mask)==0)
            {
                Active_Word.Number_of_Letters |= Mask;

                if (!Active_Word.Guess_Word.Contains(letter))
                {
                    listBIncorrectTrys.Items.Add(letter);

                    Active_Word.Wrong_Guess++;

                    int[] counter = new int[6];
                    counter[0] = 1;
                    counter[1] = 2;
                    counter[2] = 3;
                    counter[3] = 4;
                    counter[4] = 5;
                    counter[5] = 6;
                    for(int i = counter.Length - 1; i >= 0; i --)
                    {
                        string count = counter[i].ToString();
                        lbGuessesLeft.Text = (count);
                    }
                }
                lbGuessWord.Text = GetMaskedWord();

                Attempts_Made++;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `counter.Length` is never changing, so each time this loop is run, it will always terminate at `i = 0`, and `counter[0] = 1`. So, `lbGuessesLeft.Text` will always be 1.

```
for(int i = counter.Length - 1; i >= 0; i --)
{
   string count = counter[i].ToString();
   lbGuessesLeft.Text = (count);
}
```

Instead, do something like: guesses left = 6 - attempts made.

I'm not super eloquent with C#, but do something like this instead:

```
...
if (!Active_Word.Guess_Word.Contains(letter))
            {
                listBIncorrectTrys.Items.Add(letter);

                Active_Word.Wrong_Guess++;

                // Something similar to this
                // But try not to hard code constants like '6'
                lbGuessesLeft.Text = 6 - Active_Word.Wrong_Guess;
            }
            lbGuessWord.Text = GetMaskedWord();

            Attempts_Made++;
...
```

Comment: do i take out the loop and the array or put that in there with it ??

Comment: No loop needed at all :)

Comment: i did my best to clean it up